# Action Needed: iOS Distribution Certificate Expires in 30 Days

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I've received the following message from Apple but cannot find clear instructions on their website on how to do the renewal of the certificate without impacting existing users.

While there are other answers here and ones that I've found on Google but a lot of them are quite old and I'd like to make sure instructions are up to date.

How do I renew the certificate with no impact to users?

Comment: Certificates renew don't impact on existing user. The new certificates works when you submit app again on app store

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what steps should be followed?

Comment: When you have to submit the app on AppStore or tesflight then create new certificates and provisioning profile and download them and then upload build using this profiles. Delete old one.

Comment: Are you using push notifications ??

Comment: Yes but those certificates dont expire? It appears to only be my dev and distribution certificates?

Comment: Your account have multiple certificates or apps??. In which some certificates get expired. right ??

Comment: Single certificate, multiple apps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176863/discussion-between-hitesh-agarwal-and-baadier-sydow).